# What is the Apex Syntax for manually launching an Invocable Process in a Test Class?

Tags: apex

We have a mass action scheduler job that runs over-night.  This job launches an Invocable Process (Created in Process Builder).

I need to write a test class for code coverage.  In the setup area of the test class I have all the data being created which would meet the condition of the process to do something that I can then assert.

My question is, what is the Apex syntax to manually run a process?

The process itself has no parameters.  When run, it just looks for records that have been added or changed and creates or updates a record in a custom table.

**** Updated ****

Thank you for the replies.

Let me backup a bit.  This article explains why I’m asking the question and attempting to “test” my processes and flows.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_distribute_deploy_active.htm&type=5

Here is the first part of the article:

"Deploy Processes and Flows as Active

By default, active processes and flows are deployed as inactive. After deployment, you manually reactivate the new versions. If your org uses a continuous integration and continuous delivery model to deploy metadata changes, enable the option to deploy processes and flows as active. This option applies to processes and autolaunched flows that are deployed via change sets and Metadata API.
USER PERMISSIONS NEEDED
To edit process automation settings:    Customize Application

1. From Setup, enter Automation in the Quick Find box, then select Process Automation Settings.
2. Select Deploy processes and flows as active.
3. Enter the flow test coverage percentage.
4. Save your changes.
   Before you can deploy a process or autolaunched flow as active, your org must meet flow test coverage requirements. At least one Apex test must cover the flow test coverage percentage of the active processes and autolaunched flows in your org. Flow test coverage requirements don’t apply to flows that have screens.
   To calculate your org’s flow test coverage, determine the number of active autolaunched flows and processes in your org. Here’s a sample query.

   ```
   SELECT count_distinct(DefinitionId) 
   FROM Flow 
   WHERE Status = 'Active' 
     AND (ProcessType = 'AutolaunchedFlow' 
     OR ProcessType = 'Workflow' 
     OR ProcessType = 'CustomEvent' 
     OR ProcessType = 'InvocableProcess')"
   ```

As you can see, InvocableProcess are included.  The flows within the process themselves have no apex code associated with them.  They are just processes that call flows.  No actual apex code is involved to test.  Yet we are still unable to deploy these processes as “Active”.  So our conclusion from this article was that we needed to write a test class to test the processes themselves so that we can deploy our processes as active.

Thanks.

Chris

Comment: Just schedule the job directly using `System.schedule()`.

Comment: I would ask why you want to test the process, not just the Invocable Method it calls? The latter is the sensible approach; you don't need to check that the process builder flow works - that's a given - but you want to check that your Apex does what it should (and you want to ensure you have appropriate coverage for this Apex). There's no coverage requirement for flows of any form at this point that I'm aware of.

Comment: I've not tried this but all Processes are Flows under the hood so you might be able to start the invocable process using the [Apex Interview class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/flow_interview_class.htm) in the Flow namespace. Supports passing parameters

Comment: Thanks for updating the question to clarify your meaning.