# Flow Interview on Invocable Process - how to get test coverage

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, code-coverage, process, flow-interviews

I’m looking at a list of flows that don’t currently have code coverage obtained by running the following Tooling API  SOQL:

```
SELECT Definition.DeveloperName
 FROM Flow
 WHERE Status = 'Active'
    AND (ProcessType = 'AutolaunchedFlow' OR ProcessType = 'Workflow' OR ProcessType = 'CustomEvent' OR 
         ProcessType = 'InvocableProcess')
    AND Id NOT IN (SELECT FlowVersionId FROM FlowTestCoverage)
```

One of the items listed is an Involkable Process:  Now I'm told that all process are converted to flows when they are run.

So I created a test class that calls the process using Flow.Interview

```
Test.startTest();
               
Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>();
params.put('Opportunity', oDesig);
               
// Launch Flow - Create Missing Opportunity Record

Flow.Interview.Rebuild_Opportunity_Records Flow_CreateOppRecord = new Flow.Interview.Rebuild_Opportunity_Records(params);
Flow_CreateOppRecord.start() ;   // Call the Process

Test.stopTest();
```

When I run this the test fails and I get an error message:
**System.FlowException: Start can't be called on a flow with the process type Invocable Process.**

Since this call doesn’t work on an Involkable process, what do I need to do different to get  the test to run successfully and obtain code coverage for the process?

Thanks.

Chris

Comment: [related (also w/ no answer)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318569/what-is-the-apex-syntax-for-manually-launching-an-invocable-process-in-a-test-cl).  

So, in the absence of a better answer from the Community, I would figure out who calls this invocable process in your org and then do DML to get the invocable process's caller to be launched.